# Using hex in jquery's setInterval() and setTimeout()

Tags: jquery, math, scientific-notation

I am making a script that checks to see if a server is connected or has gone away.While looking around how others have done it,i realized that some are using hex inside the function.For instance `setInterval(l,6E4)`

Another example

```
setTimeout(function(){d(window.checknet.config.checkURL)},window.checknet.config.checkInterval)}a=a||{};a.checkURL=a.checkURL||window.location.href;a.checkInterval=a.checkInterval||5E3;a.warnMsg=a.msg||"No Internet connection detected, disabled features will be re-enabled when a connection is detected. ";
```

This is the use of hex `a.checkInterval=a.checkInterval||5E3;`

Why is hex being used instead of ordinary decimal figures?.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is not hex, its a number written in **[Scientific Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)**, 6 x 10<sup>4</sup>.

> = 60.000

As the time of `setInterval` is in **milliseconds**, if you want to use an `integer` as seconds, it's easy to use it like: `Ne3` being `N = seconds`.

```
1e3 = 1000 = 1 second
```

---

**Edit:**

***Hex*** numbers are written with the prefix `0x`.

Comment: Where can i learn more about writing that way i mean NE4,what notation is this?.

Comment: Nice! I found this one too: http://www.mathsisfun.com/index-notation-powers.html. This is a good way to represent huge numbers.